# How do I display the Category Title?

Tags: category

I need to be able to display the Category Title of a single category (as a h1 tag for a page displaying a list of the entries for that category).  I can successfully display the relevant entries for the category on the page, but when I have tried to display the category title it displays all of the categories titles (in a loop), not just the single category title.

My code:

```
{% if craft.request.getParam('category') is not null %}    

        {% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('category')) %}

        {% set products =  craft.entries.section('products').relatedTo(category).find() %}


        {% else %}
               {% set products = craft.entries.section('products').find() %}
        {% endif %}



<div class="top-title"> 

     {% for category in craft.categories.group('productType').find() %}       
        <header class="flush"><h1>{{ category.title }}</h1></header> 
     {% endfor %}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!
Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.slug(craft.request.getParam('category')).first() %}
```

Comment: This seems to only take the first category page. How would I get the category that is related to the current page I'm on, like, If this page has a category related to it, display that category title and link? Thanks @BradBell

Answer (score 4):

It depends how you're fetching the category. But if you've defined the template when setting up the categories it would be called be within a var called 'category', which would be a category object. You should then be able to access it using:

```
{{ category.title }}
```

If, on the other hand, you were getting the category via a slug in the URL, you would do something like:

```
{% set category = craft.categories.group('productType').slug(craft.request.lastSegment).first %}
{{ category.title }}
```

UPDATE: Following on from your updated question, you've already got the category as an object so there is no need to get it again. Try replacing:

```
// THIS IS YOUR LOOP, BTW
{% for category in craft.categories.group('productType').find() %}       
    <header class="flush"><h1>{{ category.title }}</h1></header> 
{% endfor %}
```

with:

```
{{ category.title }}
```

But you might need to add a conditional in case the page is loaded without a category. Something like:

```
{% if category | length %}
    {{ category.title }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response Clive - much appreciated.
Still struggling to get this to work....have amended code in original question (sorry - should have included this in my original post) :(

Comment: Many thanks for your response Clive - much appreciated.
I tried both those alternatives - but unfortunately, they just output nothing/blank for the Category Title.

Comment: What does `{{ craft.request.getParam('category') }}` output? And didn't you have `.first` on the end of your initial `craft.categories` query before?

Comment: I added that extra bit early today as it's the solution - apologies if I didn't make that clear!

Comment: Cool. You should accept MGX's answer below, as it better answers the question in it's current form.